# Replicate /system/files to get route or query param with full path

Tags: drupal, drupal-9, drupal-routes

I'm trying to understand how the /system/files route works in Drupal 10 (or 9).

My goal is to get a controller for a path which can have an unknown amount of subfolders and should stream files like /system/files does (with some custom behavior and permission checks).
The route would be
`/some/prefix/{node}/{filepath}` but for testing I just tried `/some/prefix/{filepath}`

First I created a path processor:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor;

use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PathProcessorFiles implements InboundPathProcessorInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
    if (str_starts_with($path, '/some/prefix/') && !$request->query->has('file') && preg_match('|^/some/prefix/(\d+)/(.+)|', $path, $matches)) {
      $request->query->set('node_id', $matches[1]);
      $request->query->set('file', $matches[2]);
      return '/some/prefix';
    }
    return $path;
  }
}
```

And a service:

```
  mymodule.files:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFiles
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 200 }
```

Next a controller and route:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class FilesController extends ControllerBase {

  public function get() {
    // Just some test.
    return [
      '#markup' => 'Test',
      '#cache' => [
        'max-age' => 0,
      ],
    ];
  }

}
```

```
mymodule.file_download:
  path: '/some/prefix/{filepath}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\FilesController::get'
  requirements:
    filepath: .+
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

While the path processor hits and finds the correct path, I get a "page not found" error.
I don't understand how this process works and what I'm missing. And where the [FileDownloadController::download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21FileDownloadController.php/function/FileDownloadController%3A%3Adownload/10) get the request param from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your path processor regex, etc. so I've reverted to a simpler version from the original `PathProcessorFiles.php` processor (/system/files)

```
    public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
      if (strpos($path, '/some/prefix/') === 0) {
        $file_path = preg_replace('|^\/some/prefix\/|', '', $path);
        $request->query->set('file', $file_path);
        return '/some/prefix';
      }
      return $path;
    }
```

Then include HttpFoundation\Request in your controller so you can extract the variable that was set above `$request->query->set('file', $file_path);`

```
    namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;
    
    use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;  // added this
    
    class FilesController extends ControllerBase {
    
      public function get(Request $request) {  // added this
        // Just some test.
        return [
          '#markup' => 'Test '.$request->query->get('file'),  // added this
          '#cache' => [
            'max-age' => 0,
          ],
        ];
      }
    
    }
```

I've been hacking at this all day, so not sure if it's the best solution.